# Find variance of binomial distribution Y in terms of the number of trials

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The random variable $Y$ has a binomial distribution with n trials and success probability $X$ where n is a given constant and $X$ is a uniform($0,1$) random variable. What is $Var(Y)$ in terms of n?

$X\sim U(0,1)$

$Y\sim B(n,X)$

$Var(Y) = E(Y^2) - E(Y)^2$

I know that
$E(Y) = E(nX) = n\times E(X) = \frac{1}{2}n$

But how do I find $E(Y^2)$?

Comment: Isn´t $Var(Y)=E(Y^2)\color{red}-[E(Y)]^2$

Comment: You're right, that was a typo. I've fixed it now.

Comment: Hint: find $EY^2$ by means of $EY^2=E[E[Y^2\mid X]]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Var(Y) = Var(E[Y|X]) + E[Var(Y|X)]$

$ = Var(nX) + E[nX(1−X)]$

$ = Var(nX) + E[nX]−E[nX^2]$

$ = n^2Var(X)+nE[X]−nE[X^2]$

$ = \frac{n^2}{12} + \frac{n}{2}−\frac{n}{3}$

$ =\frac{n^2}{12} + \frac{n}{6}$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** You can use the [Law of total variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance).

$Var(Y)=\mathbb E(Var(Y| U))+{Var}( \mathbb E(Y| U))$

$=\mathbb E(nU-nU^2)+Var(nU) $

Comment: A relation which is useful for the calculation: $\mathbb E (U^2)=Var(U)+[\mathbb E(U)]^2$. If something is still unclear, feel free to ask.

Comment: Can you give a bigger hint? How do I find $E(U^2)$ or $Var(U)$ for that matter?

Comment: @bard $\textrm{Frist approach}$: Since $U$ is standard uniform $E(U)=\int_0^1 u \cdot f_U(u) du=\int_0^1 u \cdot 1 du$. Or similar $E(U^2)=\int_0^1 u^2 \cdot f_U(u) du=\int_0^1 u^2 \cdot 1 du$. $\textrm{Second approach}$: You want to use the (well known) values of E(U) and Var(U). Then you can calculate $\mathbb E (U^2)=Var(U)+[\mathbb E(U)]^2$. / / And also note that $E(nU)=nE(u)$, since $n$ is a constant.

Comment: @bard Did you achieve any (intermediate) results?

Comment: Yes, I eventually solved it this way: $Var(Y) = Var(E[Y|X]) + E[Var(Y|X)]$

$= Var(nX) + E[nX(1-X)]$

$= n^2Var(X) + E[nX] - E[nX^2]$

$= n^2Var(X) + nE[X] - nE[X^2]$

$= \frac{n^2}{12} + \frac{n}{2} - \frac{n}{3}$

$= \frac{n^2}{12} + \frac{n}{6}$

Comment: @bard  You have made agood job,

Answer (score 1):

If $Z$ has binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $p$ then:  $$\mathbb EZ^2=\mathsf{Var}Z+(\mathbb EZ)^2=np(1-p)+ n^2p^2$$

That means  that here $$\mathbb E[Y^2\mid X]= nX(1-X)+n^2X^2$$

Now apply that: $$\mathbb EY^2=\mathbb E[\mathbb EY^2\mid X]$$

You can also go for $\mathsf{Var}Y$ immediately.

For that see the answer of callculus.

Comment: I still don't get it, how do I find $E(Y^2 | X)$?

Comment: Standard way: find an expression for $\mathbb E(Y^2\mid X=p)$. If $\mathsf{Expr}(p)$ denotes this expression then $\mathbb E(Y^2\mid X)=\mathsf{Expr}(X)$. This is exactly what I did in my answer resulting in $\mathsf{Expr}(p)=np(1-p)+n^2p^2$.